# Execute msbuild from ant after lanching vcvarsall.bat

Tags: c++, batch-file, visual-studio-2008, ant, msbuild

Good morning,
I'm trying to compile a C++ project with Ant using the VS2008 compiler (msbuild). 
This is my sequence of operation:

`<target name="setEnv" >
        <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
            <arg line="/c setEnv.bat" />
        </exec>
 </target>`

where setEnv.bat sets the enviroment variables to use msbuild

`@echo off
REM Load Visual Studio's build tools
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64`

and after it executes this

`<target name="msbuildSln" depends="setEnv">
        <exec executable="msbuild">
            <arg value="${myproj.sln}" />
            <arg value="/p:Configuration=Release" />
            <arg value="/p:Platform=x64" />
        </exec>
</target>`

The problem is that when i call the msbuild from the target msbuildSln the enviroment variable are not set in fact i have this message :

`BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\workspace\MyProj\mybuild.xml:82: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "msbuild": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

I think it is a problem of the cmd scope because if i launch it inside setEnv.bat it runs.
I've tryed different solutions :
1)Call directly msbuild from its folder and run my target 
2)Set the env. variable of vcvarsall.bat globally
3)Doing a double call to my Ant script modifying mt setEnv.bat :
`call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64 %*
ant -f mybuild.xml msbuildSln` 
setting like project default="setEnv" and removing the dependece from setEnv in the msbuildSln target.

I'm adopting the last solution but i don't know if it affects the performance. But the most important point is there a way to set and use the vcvarsall.bat and msbuild together because i have to do many steps (like checkout from svn, built solution etc..)and i want to do it with Ant not putting all in a .bat file.
Thanks.

Comment: Start Ant from within a visual studio command window, i.e. one where you already called vcvarsall.bat?

Comment: @stijin Already tried setting with cl.exe from .bat but i have the same result; it sets the variables but i can't use them when i'm back in ant. I've also tried to execute all in an <exec> like this : `<target name="setcl" >
 <exec dir="${cl.location}" executable="cmd">
  <arg value="cl" />
 </exec>
</target>`                                                           but i can't execute another program like msbuild from <arg> tag. I think i need some structure to do a nested <exec> that does not exists in Ant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute your first `cmd`:

- It spawns a new shell (inheriting that current environment of the current shell, i.e. the `ant` process).
- When that command is finished, the shell is destroyed and any non-persistent changes it may have created (such as setting variables) is lost.

Even if your `setEnv.bat` uses **[`setx`](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)** command to permanently set an environment variable, it wouldn't be available to the following ant statements/targets because the current environment (the `ant` process) will not have the new environment variables until it restarts and spawns off the system again.

*I just noticed that your `setEnv.bat` just calls another batch... why not call that batch directly?*

You need to call your `setEnv.bat` and `msbuild` within the same shell, i.e. `cmd` statement:

```
<exec dir="." executable="cmd">
    <arg line="/c setEnv.bat &amp; msbuild ${myproj.sln} /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64" />
</exec>
```

*Note the `&amp;` required to write a command line `&`*

An alternative syntax for readability:

```
<exec dir="." executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c" />
    <arg value="setEnv.bat" />
    <arg value="&amp;" />
    <arg value="msbuild" />
    <arg value="${myproj.sln}" />
    <arg value="/p:Configuration=Release" />
    <arg value="/p:Platform=x64" />
</exec>
```